# imagemagick resize - multiple files with wrong filenames after resizing .jpg images

Tags: resize, imagemagick

imagemagick resize - multiple files with wrong filenames after resizing .jpg images

**Ubuntu 14.04** and **ImageMagick 6.7.7-10**

I need to resize ~900 jpg images (kept in several folders) to several dimensions, with the current aspect ratio. I wished to start with 300px wide versions.

- I selected the first folder `1997` and I typed `convert '*.jpg[300x]' *.jpg` and the task was **successful**.

  I have 98 jpg files resized to 300px wide (and no large files as they have been overwritten.)
- I switched to the second folder `1998` and I typed in the same `convert '*.jpg[300x]' *.jpg`

  ( I also tried with `convert *.jpg -resize 300 *.jpg`, with the same result. )

  **Unexpected result:**

  - I still have the (20) old jpg files, and 39 resized files (2 pieces of each, except the last one, which has a single resized version)
  - The *filenames of the resized files* start with the *name of the last original file* and end with a counter.

  `➜  1998  ls

  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-129_angyali_udvozlet.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-130_szentek_kozossege.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-130+_szentek_kozossege.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-131_te_vagy_a_kiraly_jezus.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-132_orom.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-133_cim_nelkul.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-134_atfestve_a_sziv_megterese.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-135_ave.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-136_isten_kezeben.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-137_peter_emlekere.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-138a_aldozat.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-138b_aldozat.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-139_jelenesek.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-140_atfestve_latomas.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-141_a_zaszlos.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-142_gondviseles.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-143_az_ido_tukreben.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-144_jelenesek_ii.jpg
  i--santa_ferenc-olaj-145_jelenesek_iii.jpg`

The last original file's name `i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc.jpg` is missing from here, eventhough I can see the image in the folder view. Then the resized images come:

`i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-0.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-10.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-11.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-12.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-13.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-14.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-15.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-16.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-17.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-18.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-19.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-1.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-20.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-21.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-22.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-23.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-24.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-25.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-26.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-27.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-28.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-29.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-2.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-30.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-31.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-32.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-33.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-34.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-35.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-36.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-37.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-38.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-3.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-4.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-5.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-6.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-7.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-8.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc-9.jpg
    i--santa_ferenc-olaj-147_lanc.jpg`

**What is the problem? :'(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mogrify -resize 300 *.jpg
```

Comment: That's good, mogrify is better suited to batch operations although it does not have all the options of convert. Convert works; but for batches I include it in a script. Please can you select this as the correct answer.